# Find the next term of the series and sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$2+3+6+15+42+....$

It looks like for even numbers $(2+...+6+...+42)$ it multiplies the term by $3,7,11,...$

For odd numbers $(3+...+15+...)$ it multiples the term by $5$ and assume it will be the same as even numbers, the next will be $9$

So the next term will be $9*15=135$ but the answer says $122$ which is not sure.

Second problem is:

$(2,3,5,6,8,12,...)$

For this one, it increases as $+1,+2,+1,+2$ but it stopped at the $6th$ term.

The answer says $11$ which is not sure.

Comment: Swap tactics. For the first sequence, look at the differences between successive terms, and in the second sequence, look at every other element.

Comment: problems like these are mostly just guess work.  The list is far too short to study in any way.  Your first list could easily be [A036418](https://oeis.org/A036418), or it could just be the linear recursion $a_n=3a_{n-1}-3$ with $a_0=2$.  Actually, I think that's a better answer than the one you provide.

Comment: The answer is $42$ of course. Here is the sequence: $a_n=\frac{29n^6}{720}-\frac{71n^5}{80}+\frac{1129n^4}{144}-\frac{1687n^3}{48}+\frac{29923n^2}{360}-\frac{2849n}{30}+42$.

Comment: @ Arthur, every other element increases by $3$ $(2,...,5,...,8)$ so the answer should be $11$ but what if we wanted to see what the next number after $11$, what would be the relationship between other numbers $(...,3,...,6,...,12)$ , $21$ ? as it moves by multiple of $3$

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, observe that $$ 3-2=1=3^{0} $$ $$ 6-3=3=3^{1} $$ $$ 15-6=9=3^{2} $$ and so on. We have

> $$ a_{n+1}-a_n=3^{n}$$

where $a_0=2 , a_1=3$. Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Now it makes sense, and I found out that the provided answer is wrong. By this method, the correct answer is $123$